# Why isn't OpenVPN starting?

Tags: windows, windows-11, openvpn

I've got OpenVPN 3.3 installed on Windows 11, however following updates this morning, it is no longer starting up.

```
PS C:\Users\Sled> cd 'C:\Program Files\OpenVPN Connect\'
PS C:\Program Files\OpenVPN Connect> .\OpenVPNConnect.exe
PS C:\Program Files\OpenVPN Connect>
```

I have tried rebooting the machine, but to no effect. Likewise, I have tried reinstalling it.

What are steps I could use to diagnose this?

Answer (score 1):

So following [the suggestion from the official forums](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=34144) of deleting the file: `C:\Users\Sled\AppData\Local\Temp\.ovpn-connect-lockfile`  seemed to work for me.